# Area map showing the regions where a selected product is the most-popular

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a set of products with the sales of each product by region. I want to draw a map where the map is filtered for the areas for which the selected product is the most popular option.

I have a data set with two dimensions and one measure. The dimensions are products and geographic zip code. The measure is sales count.

My goal is to draw an area map where the zip codes for which a given selected product is the most popular.

To do this, I can use RANK() which is a table calculation, and set the specific dimensions product (checked, the addressing dimension) and zip (unchecked, the partitioning dimension). But then if the user filters on product, all the rank values collapse to 1, defeating the purpose.

In fact I have read that table calculation and level of detail calculations cannot be combined.

Is there a workaround? Or perhaps I've misunderstood something?

Comment: Can you please share your work via tableau public